# Aligning text to center if screen is smaller then 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a container with text centered. Inside the container I have a panel with the text set to left, but when the screen gets smaller then a tablet to something like a phone I want the text in the panel to center.

Here is what I am doing but not sure how media queries work and this isn't working for me.

This media query is what I'm using but hte html is a lot more complex, but left simplified as an example

```css
@@media all and (min-width:768px) {
  .text-left {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `min-width: 768px` means the code will execute if the screen has a *minimum width* of 768px. This is targeting larger screens. If you want the code to execute on screens smaller than 768px, use `max-width`. In other words, `max-width: 768px` says: *If the screen has a width up to a maximum of 768px, run the code.*

Comment: ok I just tried this but when I minimize the screen to under 768 it still doesn't align to center.

Comment: `text-align` applies to inline content. You're trying to center a `div`. Try this instead: `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: What is the css for class="container text-center" class="row"> class="panel panel-default text-left" and class="panel-body"

Comment: the css is all from bootstrap

Comment: Michael, if I uncheck the text-align css property in the debugger I get centered text, so why would I need to set margin : 0 auto ?. FYI - Shouldn't I also see the media query in the debugger? I don't

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working correctly. I was loading a partial page and my styleing was included in a @content section, which only loads on page load, not in an ajax .load.

Answer (score 2):

Your media query is being applied to anything with a `min-width` of 768px (i.e. greater than or equal to 768px). Since you want less than that you need to change it to `max-width`.

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
  .text-left {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default text-left">
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```